# Python format UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django, unicode, format

Hello I want to save string into variable like this:

```
  msg=_(u'Uživatel <a href="{0}">{1} {3}</a>').format(request.user.get_absolute_url, request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name)
```

But since the inserted variables contain characters with accents such as š I get UnicodeDecodeError even though I have set the encoding by`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

It is weird (IMHO) that it was working when I was creating this string by concatenating the variables like this:

```
msg=u'Uživatel <a href="' + request.user.get_absolute_url + ...
```

I have no clue why it shouldn't be working since its running project and I had to use such statements many times.

If you have any advice how to solve this I will be very grateful.

Comment: Apart from the problem of non-ASCII `str` being passed to `unicode.format()`, you also appear to be injecting raw strings into HTML markup, which likely represents a XSS security hole. When you create HTML from plain text variables you need to HTML-escape them before adding them to the markup string, for example using `django.utils.html.escape`.

Comment: Thats a good point. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple, I used `get_absolute_url`instead of `get_absolute_url()`. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 2):

One of your `user` lookups is returning an encoded bytestring rather than a Unicode object.

When Python 2.x is asked to concatenate Unicode and encoded bytestrings, it does so by decoding the bytestring into Unicode using the default encoding, which is `ascii` unless you go to some effort to change it. The `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` directive sets the encoding for your source code, but not the system default encoding.

From testing `format`, it looks like it tries to convert the argument to match the type of the left-hand side.

Under 2.x, things will work fine as long as the bytestring you're using can be decoded using `ascii`:

```
>>> u'test\u270c {0}'.format('bar')
u'test\u270c bar'
```

Or of course you're formatting in another Unicode object:

```
>>> u'test\u270c {0}'.format(u'bar\u270d')
u'test\u270c bar\u270d'
```

If you omit the `u` before your format, you'll get a `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
>>> 'foo {0}'.format(u'test\u270c')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u270c' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Conversely, if you format an encoded string with non-ascii bytes into a Unicode object, you'll get a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
>>> u'foo {0}'.format(test.encode('utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'd start by checking the `get_absolute_url` implementation. Valid URLs can never contain unescaped non-ascii characters, so they should always be decodable by ascii, but if you're using things built from standard Django models `first_name` and `last_name` should be Unicode objects so I'd bet on a buggy implementation of `get_absolute_url` at first.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...the reason is sooo stupid, but the traceback specifically said that the string that could not be encoded was the name. I used get_absolute_url instead of get_absolute_url().

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of the arguments to format, I guess they are 'str', not 'unicode'.
Before using them, encode them apropriatly, e.g.:

```
url = request.user.get_absolute_url
if isinstance(url, str):
    print 'url was str'
    a = url.decode('utf-8')
msg = u'Uživatel <a href="{0}">...</a>').format(url)
```

(The `if` and `print` statement is just for demonstration purpose)
Use the other values accordingly.